# Unity3d android game adding multiple plugins issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, facebook-unity-sdk

I am noob in unity3d game development.I wants to add two plugins FB and ADMOB, both individually works fine. But i am not able to keep both together. because both contains its different androidmanifest.xml, I knew it might be problem of android manifest conflict of duplicate jar. Or anything else. How can i solve it?
thanks.

Comment: Did you try deleting the duplicated jars?

Comment: yes, i did that but cant get solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on any individual android manifest, you should write your own android manifest for your own application, uniting the two manifests of the plugins that you're using. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) can help you on writing down a correct manifest. Also, just by googling "unity android manifest merge", you can find posts from a lot of people solving various individual issues relating to merging android manifests, like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/735848/how-to-merge-multiple-androidmanifestxml-files.html), [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/655236/merging-androidmanifestxml.html) and [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/699737/how-can-i-merge-two-android-manifestxml-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install Facebook plugin, and then follow [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/games#unity) instruction.

Facebook and Google AdMob plugins don't require to extend Unity's main Activity.

You can find more information regarding those plugins at this [WebSite](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html).